# Check if block has already been rendered

Tags: blocks

During an observer is there a way to determine if a block has been rendered or not?

I can grab the block like so:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('the_block_layout_name');
```

But i want to check if it has already been rendered - i..e its toHtml has been called.

Is this possible?  if so how and if not are there any other ideas on how to achieve this or something similar?

Comment: what are you planning on doing with it? I dont know about checking a block in an observer but what about `core_block_abstract_to_html_after`?

Comment: I have an observer that is going to add some html to a block but i need to know if it was already rendered or not

Comment: ah ok, is it a core event? if so which one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no property in the `$block` which is set. But as David said, you can hook into `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` and just do something like:

```
public function coreBlockAbstractToHtmlAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
$block = $observer->getBlock();
$block->setIsRenderer(true);
}
```

Then you can just check at any time: `if($block->getIsRenderer())` if the block was already rendered.

Of course you can do everything else in this event. And you can check inside the observer:

```
if($block instanceof Mage_WhateverModule_Block_Whatever_Block_You_Want)
```